# Munit issue Error creating bean with name muleNotificationManager

Tags: mule, munit

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: 
>   Error creating bean with name '_muleNotificationManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
>   Error creating bean with name '_muleTransactionManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customTxManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleTransactionManager': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question lacks [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some description

Answer (score 0):

Few things to evaluate here.
1. Make sure you installed the Munit plugin in anypoint studio.
2. Make sure you added property files to context spring:beans>
context:property-placeholder location="UAT.properties" />
spring:import resource="classpath:Implementation.xml"/>   --Probably you only had this one./spring:beans>

Comment: tried with this but still facing issue any other alternative way